# Does VS Code's Settings Sync feature store the settings on GitHub?

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm logged in to VS Code (version 1.7.3.1, windows) using my github account and have turned on the settings sync. However, I am unable to locate the synced settings on my GitHub account. How can I find the synced settings files on GitHub?

Comment: GitHub is likely used only for authentication, not for storage.

Answer (score 1):

From the docs at https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/settings-sync#_can-i-use-a-different-backend-or-service-for-settings-sync,

> Settings Sync uses a dedicated service to store settings and coordinate updates. A service provider API may be exposed in the future to allow for custom Settings Sync backends.

The settings aren't stored anywhere under your GitHub account on GitHub. Also, there's the fact that GitHub signin isn't the only signin option (there's also Microsoft signin).

Note also/though that [GitHub Codespaces](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/codespaces) (which you can interact with via VS Code locally or in a browser) allow you to configure a GitHub "dotfiles repo". See https://docs.github.com/en/codespaces/customizing-your-codespace/personalizing-github-codespaces-for-your-account#dotfiles.